# T4 Entity Framework get Element Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, t4

I'm trying to edit a T4 template for Entity Framework. My current T4 template is able to extract the TypeName but this is fully qualified with the name space, something like this:

```
foreach (AssociationType association in GetSourceSchemaTypes<AssociationType>())
{
    <#=EscapeEndTypeName(association, 0, code)#>
}
```

I can't for the life of me work out how to just get the type name by itself without the fully qualified namespace. Can anyone put me out of my misery?

I can see later on there is access via the object set, but I don't have access to that at this point.

Comment: Or find "EscapeEndTypeName" in your TT and create your own "EscapeEndTypeShortName". Also, you can debug the TT to see what is going on in the escaping method.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I didn't realise that EscapeEndTypeName was generated, I had assumed it was a built in method. Thats great, thank you